# Variable use in conditional not working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I have 10 of these in my HTML:

```
<div class="resultContainer">
   <div class="twitchResult" id="charionna">
      <a class="link" href="https://www.twitch.tv/charionna"target="_blank">
         <h3 class="username">charionna</h3>
         <p class="streamInfo"></p>
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I make an request to the Twitch API:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/comster404/?client_id=mlrx1e94dg7yus5yqm26lwpyxrg9j9x');
 xhr.onreadystatechange = twitchInfo;
 xhr.send();
```

and the server responds with a non-200 status code I have the response handler function run the
`callSuccessChecker` function like this:

```
function twitchInfo() {


     // request NOT succesful
     if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status !== 200) {

     //  console.log('This is working');

     callSuccessChecker();

     }
}
```

This part is working just fine.

It's the `callSuccessChecker` that's an issue. Specifically, using a variable that's I declared in it in a conditional. Like so:

```
function callSuccessChecker() {

      var containerList = document.getElementsByClassName('resultContainer');
      var closedText = document.createTextNode('account closed');

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {// <--------not working YET

          if(containerList[i].style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(245, 209, 107)') {

          containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1].appendChild(closedText);
          }
     // console.log (containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1]);
     }
}
```

In this function you can see I have commented out a console.log at the bottom. When I use `containerList[i]` here, it shows me the output in the console.

But when I do the same thing (as is visible in the function) inside the `if` statement and object, it doesn't seem to work/activate/grab it/whatever the correct term for that is.

Here are the styles for the container whose backgroundColor I'm trying to check against in the conditional (I converted the hex code into its RGB equivalent in the conditional):

```
.resultContainer {
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px white solid;
    background-color: #F5D16B;
}
```

Any explanations as to why this is?

Is it the conditional itself that is off?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used `consol.log()` for the background color to see if it meets the `if` condition?

Comment: Javascript rarely returns hex colors, most likely RGB, depending on browser, which is why such checks shouldn't be done.

Comment: @adeneo - Ah, I did notice in the console that it returned an RGB, and realized I should change it from hex to RGB, but it slipped my mind until you reminded me of it just now.

I'll go and change it and update after doing so.

Comment: I'm using this: console.log (document.getElementById('charionna').parentNode.style.backgroundColor);
and it showed me a background color once, but not it just displays a "10"  and a blank line(due to the for loop) and no rgb. So it's working, but not actually displaying the background-color value.

Answer (score 0):

There might be problem of comparsion of color value. How about:

```
function isEqualColor(a, b) {
    var elementA = document.createElement("div"),
        elementB = document.createElement("div");
    elementA.style.backgroundColor = a;
    elementB.style.backgroundColor = b;
    return elementA.style.backgroundColor == elementB.style.backgroundColor;
}

function callSuccessChecker() {
    var containerList = document.getElementsByClassName('resultContainer');
    var closedText = document.createTextNode('account closed');

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(isEqualColor(containerList[i].style.backgroundColor, '#F5D16B')) {
            containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1].appendChild(closedText);
        }
        console.log(containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, but thanks for trying. I'm not getting any errors in regards to my use of "appendChild", and besides what adeneo mentioned above in his comment about hex codes, the problem seems to be with the variable "containerList" not working in the conditional or conditional object.

Comment: Check it out :)

Comment: I'm getting: "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined"

Comment: Ups! I like an idiot worng named variables :o Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This block of `console.logs` should help you determine where in the chain the object is breaking:

```
if(containerList[i].style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(245, 209, 107)') {
    console.log(containerList[i]);
    console.log(containerList[i].children[0]);
    console.log(containerList[i].children[0].children[0]);
    console.log(containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1]);
    containerList[i].children[0].children[0].children[1].appendChild(closedText);
}
```

If all of these print out non-null, then the `appendChild()` should work.

You can also try a different way of reading `backgroundColor`, like so:

```
if(containerList[i].currentStyle['background-color'] == 'rgb(245, 209, 107)') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: It printed out nothing at all when used inside the "if" object, which means the conditional was not met?...and that the problem is still "containerList[ i ]" it seems...

When I used the block of consoles outside of the "if" object, they worked and all printed out non-null, so appendChild() is working fine.

Comment: @Edson Yes that means the if condition is not being met. Please put this line `console.log(containerList[i].style.backgroundColor);` before the if() statement to observe the color before the if checks it and manually determine if condition is met.

Comment: It seems to be working, but instead of showing the value of the property, all I see is a blank space. 

This has been the case every time I try to get the backgroundColor value in the console, except for a few times, which were an exception for some odd reason, since the code was the same.

Comment: Can you update your OP to show us how `twitchInfo()` is being called in the context of this problem.

Comment: I added the xhr request that results in the non-200 status code response and that uses twitchInfo() as the response handler.

Comment: And is there any other code modifying the style attributes of your resultContainers? It seems that whatever you're expecting to set your container to a certain backgroundColor is not actually happening, or something else is overriding it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information...look for alternate ways to read the `background-color` of a DOM element with javascript